# Swedish vs Norwegian vs Danish. What the easiest language to learn for a native-Russian speaker with C1-level English?

Tags: russian, danish, norwegian, swedish

Swedish vs Norwegian vs Danish, What's the easiest language to learn, overall?

I am native in Russian, but pretty good at English (C1).

The purposes of learning new language would be to be able to attend a nordic university as an undergraduate student.

Physics is the major I am interested in, so a lot of Mathematical and Technical vocabulary could be invovled.

Can't wait for your tips!

Comment: Sorry but the English level is completely irrelevant. So which country do you plan to emigrate to?

Comment: In this case I am just looking for all options to get an undergraduate degree outside of Russia.

However, United Stateses seems to be attractive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those Scandinavic languages have their own pecularities. Danish pronunciation is special, but all of them share very much grammar and vocabulary. Swedish is the largest and has generally good resources. Norwegian has a strong Duolingo course, while Danish has an active contributor on Tatoeba and thereby lots of correct sentences on sites drawing from it.

But basically you have no wrong choices: pick any, and you can shift to any other with little effort. Also, the elder generation in each country understands the other languages, while the youngsters might have a bit of an initial threshold to cross.

My background: I studied (but did not learn) Swedish at school, moved to Denmark for one year and have now lived several years in Norway. Jumping from Danish to Norwegian was easy.

Comment: What is your native language? Were the languages particularly difficult/easy to learn in the context of work or educational studies?

Comment: Finnish, which we also speak at home. My working language in Denmark was English and in Norway was English to start with, though I started pretty actively using Norwegian. I worked at research mathematics.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know anything about attending European colleges for graduate programs that are taught mostly in English?

May be you are also aware of some tips related to getting a researcher position in Europe (with English as the work language)?

Comment: Scandinavic? Please check your text before posting.

Comment: @Lambie Please feel free to edit; everyone can edit to improve the answers and the questions, and it is lower effort to everyone than commenting.

Comment: @EmmaLincoln I feel your extra questions are outside the scope of this SE site and a comment tread.